# Join two tables and update third table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables `tblN1` and `tblN2` to get the number of total access for user and update the third table `tblNCC` without success because I have error:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 't.UserN1' in 'on clause'
```

I don't understand this error ... the column `t.UserN1` is in Select sql query.

Maybe the problem is the `Union All` syntax ?

My code below, please help me.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
UPDATE tblNCC AS CC
JOIN (
    SELECT
        sum(total) AS Total
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*) AS Total,
                UserN1
            FROM
                `tblN1`
            WHERE
                UserN1 IN ('7047505')
            AND dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
            AND CURDATE()
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*) AS Total,
                    UserN2
                FROM
                    `tblN2`
                WHERE
                    UserN2 ('7047505')
                AND dateN2 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
                AND CURDATE()
        ) AS t
) AS q ON t.UserN1 = CC.UserNcc
SET CC.Total = t.Total;
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 't.UserN1' in 'on clause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` is not in the scope. it's inside `q`.

You probably mean something like this:

```
UPDATE tblNCC AS CC
JOIN (
    SELECT
        username,
        sum(total) AS Total
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*) AS Total,
                UserN1 as username
            FROM
                `tblN1`
            WHERE
                UserN1 IN ('7047505')
            AND dateN1 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
            AND CURDATE()
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*) AS Total,
                    UserN2 as username
                FROM
                    `tblN2`
                WHERE
                    UserN2 ('7047505')
                AND dateN2 BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
                AND CURDATE()
        ) AS t
) AS q ON q.username = CC.UserNcc
SET CC.Total = q.Total;
```